# md-slider not updating when its model value is updated from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

My HTML code is following which contains `md-slider`

```
<body ng-app="ABC">

    <div class="ctrl" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <md-slider ng-model="threshold" md-discrete min="1" max="100" aria-label="threshold"></md-slider>

    </div>
</body>
```

This is my controller:

```
angular.module("ABC", ["ngMaterial"])
       .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.threshold = localStorage.getItem("myExtThreshold");
});
```

When I slide the slider using mouse, `threshold` is updated in controller. However when I change `threshold` in controller, the slider position doesn't change. For example, if I change `threshold` value from 20 to 60, and I use `console.log($scope.threshold)` the value shown will be 60 but the `md-slider` remain at 20.

`localStorage.getItem("myExtThreshold")` returns valid numeric value.

Comment: `myExtThreshold` is this single value or object in local storage?

Comment: it's single numeric value in range 1 to 100. I console.log it and it's correct value. I also console.log after assigning it to threshold and threshold value do gets updated. It just doesn't make slider move to new position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the controller. Of course nothing wrong with your code. just making the return value to be a number

```
$scope.threshold = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myExtThreshold"))
```

Comment: Accept or upvote if it helps. So, that others can go to a better solution when they see this question

Comment: To my surprise, it's working. Thank You! But I didn't get it. JSON.parse will make it JSON object rather than number right?

Comment: If the value in JSON.parse() is a string number like "123", or boolean like "true", it will convert them to primitive types like `123` and `true`